# Is it possible to generate a team which will beat at least 2-3 teams from 6 other teams which I know

Tags: combinations, probability

Scenario.
11 Member team (From 20 members) and 7 member participating including me.

Now I know rest 6 teams, I've to create my 7th team such that it will beat at least 2-3 teams. Can we deal with how many players have been selected by others based on their frequency of being picked by others.

This is for Cricket Dream team for a match, we've to select the players from both the teams to create own team of 11.

Is it possible to generate that sort of team which will beat at least 2-3 teams and how?

Comment: What characteristics about a team or a player make it possible for a team to "beat" another?

Comment: @ggorlen Every player will get points, based on real match performance.

Comment: OK--what's a match? Performing what exactly? My point here in asking these questions is that I'm suggesting that the question is vaguely defined. I can't tell you how to select a "good" team if I don't know what the objective of the game is or what characteristics players or teams have that make them good at attaining that objective. In other words, I can't pick a good basketball team if I don't know the rules of the game or anything about the players.

Comment: @ggorlen I've updated the description.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming. This question is a better fit on https://math.stackexchange.com